# Vim: Docs on syntax IDs and what they're used on

Tags: vim

I'm currently building my own color scheme for Vim, and I'm doing so by adding to an existing config I got from who-knows-where and editing it as I see fit.

The problem is that there's no description for the syntax IDs, as far as I can tell. For example, even with standard Vim IDs, how am I supposed to know what `ColorColumn` refers to? `PmenuSbar`? With so many IDs it's impossible to guess and check to see what refers to what.

Then you open that up with other languages and plugins and it becomes even more complicated.

I get that with plugins you're probably at the mercy of whoever wrote them, but at least for standard, in-built syntax highlighting, is there any documentation somewhere on what all these refer to? I cannot find anything for some of these keys, even by searching for them individually.

Ideally this would be something as simple as I can place my cursor on `ColorColum` in my color config file, run some command, and get a description for what that key refers to.

Comment: How about `:help highlight-default`

Comment: @j1-lee works brilliantly. Couldn't find anything that led me to that command online. 
Care to add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, glad it helped!

Comment: Instead of relying on random internet searches, I'd suggest you take some time to learn how the built-in documentation works. Case in point, `:h ColorColumn` leads *directly* to the appropriate section while `:h colorcolumn<C-d>` (all lowercase because that's easier) lists two 100% relevant candidates, and `:h PmenuSbar` (case-sensitive or not) also leads *directly* to the appropriate section.

Comment: @romainl Why would I want to guess at commands when I can find documentation elsewhere?

Comment: Guessing is what you are currently doing, and not very successfully at that. Learn how to use the built-in help and you won't have to guess anything ever… or count on your luck… or on others. "Learn to use the built-in help." is the only viable answer to "how am I supposed to know what $FOO refers to?".

Comment: @romainl No, guessing is blindly trying commands until I happen across something that works. That would be stupid.

Comment: This is an apt description of your current strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the explanations for the default highlight groups (e.g., `ColorColumn` or `PmenuSel`) at `:help highlight-default`.

Answer (score -1):

Worst SEO in the world but I eventually found this site which goes over some of the inbuilt syntax: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html